# Create a Safe with the same address on the BSC chain

Tags: gnosis-safe

My address :
0x0260508D8159cED0e56bd0Bd4A8Bbc8d2557c77e

I've created a safe on Ethereum here :
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x46e54711accb6faa5059f0a6b080e34dd39492b3dc41ccf18986f6ed9760748a

I try to create with the same address on the BSC
https://bscscan.com/address/0x0260508D8159cED0e56bd0Bd4A8Bbc8d2557c77e

Following this tutorial :
https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741

I've been paste on HEX DATA
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

Please find a tx on BSC :
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6b96787e15ccd78b1c3bce108caca093ef9cae0de14cbba648bda47795954794

But something is wrong, it doesn't create the contract at the end. We can see in the video at 2:53

Can you please help me, to do the good things by having this address on BSC?

I will explain why I have to do this.
Because we have staked our DAO token on the DAO Maker platform, some payment must be done from the BSC chain in BUSD, but as the registered address with the stacked DAO is 0x0260508D8159cED0e56bd0Bd4A8Bbc8d2557c77e
I must have the same address on the BSC network to make the payment because being stacked with this address gives me the right to pay the launchpad.

If not, the staking will last 2 years and the funds are blocked it will be nice learning in my first safe :-)

I hope you can help me about this issue, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send that payload to the Gnosis Safe: Proxy Factory on the BSC network, that is at address [0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2](https://bscscan.com/address/0xa6b71e26c5e0845f74c812102ca7114b6a896ab2). That transaction will then create a Safe at address 0x0260508D8159cED0e56bd0Bd4A8Bbc8d2557c77e.

Your transactions currently do nothing because you tried to send them directly to the not yet existent Safe address (0x0260508D8159cED0e56bd0Bd4A8Bbc8d2557c77e). And please note that would not be the proper recipient anyway ;)

Comment: Thank you for the very clear clarification and your very quick answer. 
Everything is ok, I am very happy and I understood my mistake.